# How Can I convert Exponential form back to a number?

Tags: excel

I am trying to convert exponential form to a number but I can't figure out how it has to be done.

I have a number `1820674000000385406`.

I am pasting this number excel after saving  this I am following these steps
Format cells->Number and selecting the type.

but after doing this I am not getting my original number I am getting the number as `1820674000000380000`

but I want my original number back. Please help me with this.

Comment: You're pasting it from where? When you have large number and you need to keep the precision, you need to insert it in excel as text. Either click in the formula bar, put `'` and paste your number, or use the text import wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Excel has a limited resolution of 15 digits for the this type as you can see here:
[Excel specifications and limits](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)

Thus Excel saves 182067400000038E+04, which are the 15 first digits of your number and the corresponding exponential.

If you want to keep your number as it is, I recommend you to use a database instead. Excel is not made for these kind of huge numbers.

Best

Comment: +1 for the first part of the answer.  As to moving to a database, yes that's one way to go.  There are other ways to handle large numbers in excel too.  What's best for the op depends on what how (s)he wants to use the data

Answer (score 1):

While storing you can app ' before the number. This would stop excel from converting the number.

Example - 1820674000000385406 would be stored as '1820674000000385406

Another work around is to store number as text. By formatting the cells as to type text.

More details you can find [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/214233)